# c# exponential format removing zeros

Tags: c#, format, exponential

I am using exponential format like this:

> equationNumber.text = result.ToString("e6",
>   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

I would like to remove zeros before "e" and have max 6 decimal places for example if I have output:

> 1.000000e9

I would like to recieve:

> 1e9

or

> 1.000600e10  = 1.0006e10

Comment: Maybe you should look up what "e6" does.

Comment: do a google search on the exact text here
`C# stackoverflow Exponential format` see how many results come up.. perhaps you should try to use google for the `unknown`

Comment: `i.ToString("0.######E0",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stick to the general formats, you can get something close to what you are looking for. Example `number.ToString("g6", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` will return “1.0006e+10”. The following MSDN link my prove useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx